# How do we pass the server ID to a server endpoint to a Storage sync aka file sync service through an ARM template

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-files

```
 *"type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/serverEndpoints"
    {
                "type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/registeredServers",
                "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('FilesyncName'), '/rs')]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices', parameters('FilesyncName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "agentVersion": "XXXX",
                    "serverOSVersion": "XXXX",
                    "lastHeartBeat": "XXXXX",
                    "serverRole": "Standalone",
                    "clusterId": "XX",
                    "serverId": "XXXXX",
                    "friendlyName": "XXXXXXXX"
                }
            },
             {
                "type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/serverEndpoints",
                "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('FilesyncName'),'/',parameters('syncgroupname'),'/','-se')]", 
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups', parameters('FilesyncName'), parameters('syncgroupname'))]",
                    "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices', parameters('FilesyncName'))]",
                    "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/registeredServers', parameters('FilesyncName'), 'rs')]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "serverLocalPath": "F:\\",
                    "cloudTiering": "On",
                    "volumeFreeSpacePercent": 20,
                    "tierFilesOlderThanDays": 7,
                    "friendlyName": "XXXX",
                    "serverResourceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/registeredServers', parameters('FilesyncName'), 'rs')]",
                    "offlineDataTransfer": "On",
                    "offlineDataTransferShareName": "fsnew",
                    "initialDownloadPolicy": "NamespaceOnly",
                    "localCacheMode": "UpdateLocallyCachedFiles"
                }
            }*
```

The above resource type and the ARM TEMPLATE for adding the server end points.
This template doesn't trigger the provisioning the server end-point. Would like to see an example of the same.TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a working ARM template that deploys a Storage Sync Service, a Sync Group and a Server Endpoint.

You can get the `serverResourceId` property when you register the server with your Storage sync server as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207314/10805761), but in the ResourceId format:

```
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/mystoragesyncservice/registeredServers/85fa92da-2b2e-447c-d3rg-f8bf43c4064f
```

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storagesyncservicename": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "mystoragesyncservice"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices",
            "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
            "name": "[parameters('storagesyncservicename')]",
            "location": "westus2",
            "properties": {
                "incomingTrafficPolicy": "AllowAllTraffic"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storagesyncservicename'), '/mystoragesyncgroup')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices', parameters('storagesyncservicename'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/serverEndpoints",
            "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storagesyncservicename'), '/mystoragesyncgroup/5770750b-a1e6-4910-9781-1482fdee757a')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups', parameters('storagesyncservicename'), 'mystoragesyncgroup')]",
                "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices', parameters('storagesyncservicename'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "serverLocalPath": "D:\\Data",
                "cloudTiering": "Off",
                "volumeFreeSpacePercent": 20,
                "friendlyName": "mytestafs",
                "serverResourceId": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/mystoragesyncservice/registeredServers/85fa92da-2b2e-447c-d3rg-f8bf43c4064f",
                "offlineDataTransfer": "Off",
                "initialDownloadPolicy": "NamespaceThenModifiedFiles",
                "localCacheMode": "UpdateLocallyCachedFiles"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any reason why not. its just a regular provider in Azure ARM api.

Comment: Can you please detail it on how that can be implemented. I have followed the microsoft docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storagesync/2019-06-01/storagesyncservices/syncgroups/serverendpoints)

Comment: yeah, thats how you do it, i don't have a readymade template - i've never done this, but I dont see why you would have any issues with doing that. if you cant find docs on how to do that - you can use wireshark or fiddler or developer tools in your browser to capture whatever the portal is doing when you create that resource in the portal and replicate in the template

Comment: The issue is is registering a server before adding a server end point through ARM TEMPLATE and passing the resource id for the same.

Comment: show your code and what doesnt work exactly. you can use `dependsOn` for ordering and `reference()\resourceId()` to retrieve data