# How to register a server for an Azure file sync using ARM TEMPLATE

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-files, azure-storage-files

The below lines of code is an arm template section that I tried and didn't work for me.

```
 {
        "type": "microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/registeredServers",
        "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storagesyncname'), 'xxx')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices', parameters('storagesyncname'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "agentVersion": "11.1.0.0",
            "serverOSVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "lastHeartBeat": "2021-02-09T12:36:34.36877Z",
            "serverRole": "Standalone",
            "clusterId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "serverId": "xxxx",
            "friendlyName": "xxx"
        }
    }
```

Comment: How're you trying to deploy and what is the error you see?

Comment: I have an issue passing the server id from template

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, using an ARM template to register a server isn't a supported approach. As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-server-registration), you can register a server as follows:

- Download the Azure File Sync agent and install it on all servers you want to sync.
- After finishing the agent install, you can either:

  - use the server registration utility that opens to register the server to a Storage Sync Service, or
  - use the [Register-AzStorageSyncServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storagesync/register-azstoragesyncserver?view=azps-5.5.0) cmdlet from the [Az.StorageSync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storagesync/?view=azps-5.5.0) module to register the server with a Storage Sync service. Note that this command has to be run on the server you want to register.

    ```
    Register-AzStorageSyncServer -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -StorageSyncServiceName "myStorageSyncServiceName"
    ```

You will then get the `ServerId` in the output.

At this point, if you browse to your Storage Sync Service in the Azure portal, you should be able to see your server listed in the **Registered servers** blade. PowerShell or the Azure portal can then be used to configure sync on this server.